# Object key exist outside of the function call but not inside the function scope

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am working with fabric.js and at one point I use this code:

```
canvas.on("object:modified", (opt) => {
  console.log(opt.action); //="scale"
  handleScaled(opt);
});
```

But in the `handleScaled` function `opt.action` is undefined:

```
function handleScaled(opt) {
  console.log(opt.action) //=undefined
  console.log(opt) //displays the whole opt object but there is no "action" in it
  //further handleScaled code
}
```

`console.log(opt.action)` before the function call would display "scale" correctly but then when I call the same in `handleScaled`, `opt.action` is undefined.

Why doesn't `opt.action` seem to exist in the scope of the called function but happens to exist before the call?

Correct working code that only calls `handleScale` when the action was "scale":

```
canvas.on("object:modified", (opt) => {
  if (opt.action === "scale") {
    handleScaled(opt);
  }
});
```

Comment: You probably have more than one call happening of `on` with different scenarios: sometimes `action` is defined, sometimes not. Please provide (the minimal necessary) code which we can run to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you sure the two console logs are from the same call ? It seems weird anyway to call handleScaled without being sure the action is a scaling action.

Comment: @trincot yes, there is another "object:modified", that calls a "handleMod" function. The scale function is to check a minimum and maximum scale while the "handleMod" function is implementing an undo history by saving the modified objects to a list. In old versions of fabric.js I was using "object:scaled" here but that event was removed. Sorry I can try to provide a minimal code but I am tight on time right now.

Comment: @Peterrabbit that's why I use the code mentioned at the end. It works and looks proper enough to me but the question was just for understanding why it behaves this way.

Comment: Not all modifications have an action. For example, changing text content (without moving or resizing) will cause the `"object:modified"` event to fire without `opt.action`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r but I am scaling the object...

Comment: As suggested earlier, you have multiple calls of `on` and are probably confused by the console.log outputs, mixing up output from different events.

Comment: just step debug it...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when you log `opt.action` before calling the `handleScaled` function, it displays "scale" correctly because it is accessing the `action` property of the `opt` object within the callback function passed to the `canvas.on` event handler. When you log `opt.action` inside the `handleScaled` function, it shows as `undefined` because the `opt` object being passed to the `handleScaled` function is a different instance of the object. It doesn't have the `action` property because it is not the same `opt` object that was logged previously.

To make `opt.action` is accessible within the `handleScaled` function, you can modify your code like this:

```js
canvas.on("object:modified", (opt) => {
  console.log(opt.action); //="scale"
  handleScaled(opt);
});

function handleScaled(opt) {
  console.log(opt.action); // "scale" (should display correctly)
  // further handleScaled code
}
```

By passing the `opt` object directly to the `handleScaled` function, you retain access to its properties within the function scope. Make sure that the `opt` object you pass to `handleScaled` contains the `action` property as expected.

Comment: What is different to my provided code?